# MS Excel, multiple rows, copy data using VLOOKUP if there are multiple rows with same values

Tags: excel, duplicates, rows, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following data.

```
ID        lastname           firstname           dob
------------------------------------------------------
123       Alderson           Sophie             01-01-1900
456                          Sophie
5573      Alderson           Sophie
```

I am trying to achieve something with a combination of *[VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)* function and some conditional statements, but going in circles.

All the records belong to one person (Alderson-sophie) in this case. There may be 1 record or more for the same person. But all rows may or may not have the same information as shown.

So, I need to copy any information(cells) in the other rows belonging to the same person and  to the first row (which will be considered the primary row), making sure that if there is a difference in data between the rows, the values are copied to it and the rows other than the first one are left as it is/made blank.

Any help / pointers please..

Advance Thanks

Comment: What is the criteria of separating persons? Or simply: how do you understand sample records belong to ONE person? It's may be obvious for human, but not for Excel: there must be precise set of conditions.

Comment: At the moment, its not very stringent. I had this question on my mind as well. Apparently its the lastname AND (firstname OR dob)

Comment: That's still not enough... What should it do with only one of 3 available? ignore or whatever? Please provide more precise conditions.

Comment: The first row will have the collated information from all the rows belonging to the same user, and for the rest of the rows the fields where a match has been found will be reset to blank.

If there is a field, say twitter, and a user has two different usernames on two different rows, they will stay intact (these wouldn't be reset to blank) - to preserve information.

ex:
lastname  firstname twitter
---------------------------
alderson            abc123
alderson  Sophie    def123

Result
---------
Alderson Sophie abc123
                def123

Answer (score 1):

What if you created your own key column? Perhaps concatenate the ID, Surname and First name to create a unique code? That's what we do with our sheets.